# It is very very slow to change filtered DataRows of DataTable in c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, datatable

There is a code here with 2 `DataTables`. Both of them are filled with a `SqlDataAdabter` from SQL Server 2012.  There are 15.000 rows in `dtParticipants` and 80.000 rows in `dtSubjectResult`.

```
foreach (DataRow rowPart in dtParticipants.Rows)
{
    int partId = int.Parse(rowPart["main_id"].ToString());
    string partUserCode = rowPart["o_user_code"].ToString();

    DataRow[] filteredRows = dtSubjectResult.Select("main_id = " + partId);
    if (filteredRows == null)
        continue;

    foreach (DataRow row in filteredRows)
    {
        row["correct_count"] = 5;//unit.CorrectCount;
        row["incorrect_count"] = 15;//unit.IncorrectCount;
        row["empty_count"] = 20;//unit.EmptyCount;
        row["net_count"] = 12;//unit.Total;
    }//foreach 2
}//foreach 1
```

But this code is very very slow... When I comment codes inside second foreach, code runs very normal without any speed problem.

Interesting is that when I try this code like this, it works very well.

```
foreach (DataRow row in dtSubjectResult.Rows)
{
    row["correct_count"] = 5;//unit.CorrectCount;
    row["incorrect_count"] = 15;//unit.IncorrectCount;
    row["empty_count"] = 20;//unit.EmptyCount;
    row["net_count"] = 12;//unit.Total;
}
```

So what is the problem... IS looping through filtered rows slow? I don't know??

Comment: i suspect, multiple filtering operations (`dtSubjectResult.Select("main_id = " + partId);`) are slow

Comment: Filtering on client-side, very nice at syntactical level and short code, can be VERY slow and using VERY big count of objects (hard to garbage collector)

Comment: How many rows are in the `DataTable`? and if this is a big number: *why* is it? Heck: why are you using `DataTable` *at all*?

Comment: There are 15.000 rows in dtParticipants and 80.000 rows in dtSubjectResult. So what do you advice? SqlDataReader?

Comment: Can you make the filtration in the sql query?

Comment: Yes, I can use filtration in the sql query. But in this case I must use SqlDataReader, am I correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

multiple filtering operation is a serious performance hit

```
DataRow[] filteredRows = dtSubjectResult.Select("main_id = " + partId);
```

`Select` needs to interpret filter expression, scan 80k rows in `dtSubjectResult` on each of 15k iteration

`Join` 2 tables and update `dtSubjectResult` rows in one go:

```
var grouped = dtParticipants.AsEnumerable()
    .Join(dtSubjectResult.AsEnumerable(),
          rPart => (int)rPart["main_id"],
          rSubj => (int)rSubj["main_id"],
          (rPart, rSubj) => new { P = rPart, S = rSubj })
    .GroupBy(x => x.P["main_id"]);

foreach (var gr in grouped)
{
    foreach (var row in gr)
    {
        row.S["correct_count"] = 5;//unit.CorrectCount;
        row.S["incorrect_count"] = 15;//unit.IncorrectCount;
        row.S["empty_count"] = 20;//unit.EmptyCount;
        row.S["net_count"] = 12;//unit.Total;
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried it, but it gives an error: Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'AnonymousType#1'